# Unable to connect to an AWS instance through putty or VNCviewer but able to ssh through gitbash. Having "Network Error: Connection Timed Out"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, putty, git-bash, vnc-viewer

I've been using a linux(ubuntu) GUI instance in AWS for almost 2 weeks for now. I've been working on flask application using Python. I followed the steps from the AWS website to deploy an flask application on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. As I was about to complete deploying the application after installing everything, putty and VNCviewer were not responding.

I was having a "Network error: Connection timed out". I tried looking up on stackoverflow and other sources including AWS website for any help. 
The only thing that i found out was to restart the instance. I tried that and it's still not working. But, I did a ssh from gitbash command prompt and it's letting me do that. Any thoughts and help is really appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: If you can SSH to the instance using gitbash then I see no reason why you cannot also SSH to the instance using Putty, as long as you are on the same machine, indicating the same port  number (22), the same host DNS name, and the same private key.

Comment: Exactly, that's my point. I am on the same machine with the same port number and same host dns and same private key. I don't see anything wrong. But it's giving a network error: connection timed out.

Comment: I would try IP address rather than host name and double-check the Putty settings.

Comment: I was trying the IP address and i got the error. Now, after a while. I just clicked it and it works now in Putty but not vncviewer. I'll try that as well.

Comment: Presumably you have checked that the VNC server on that host is running.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the VNC server on the host. It was giving me a connection error. Now finally, what I did was. Reboot the AWS instance and ssh after few minutes and both are working fine now but I'm unable to see my GUI. That's okay for now. I guess that solves it. Thank You.

Comment: TIP: Just a addition. Keep track of your Public IP once you restart your instance. Use that IP to ssh to your instance. just a addon.